# Drive hash value changed when filename changed within drive

Tags: file, hash, drive

I just want to better understand why the drive hash value changes when I change the name of a file that is contained within that drive. I have just started working with hashes and I understand that a file hash value changes when the contents of the file change. I guess I'm just wondering if that applies here, since the contents of the drive are changing when I change the name of the file in it.

Comment: What "drive"? What technology are you referring to?

Comment: I am using "FTK Imager" to determine the hash of a USB drive. I have a single .txt file on the USB. I changed the name of the file (which has no affect on the file hash value), but it changed the drive hash value. I just do not fully understand why it changed. I think it relates to changing the contents of the drive, but am unsure.

Comment: the file name has to be stored somewhere. Where do you think the name of the file is stored? How would changing the file name have no affect the 1's and 0's saved in the drive?

Comment: So my original assumption about changing the contents of the drive is correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you change anything on a drive it will change the "hash" value of the memory because the hash is a unique representation of the contents of the thing being hashed. This includes file names which includes file locations (in a folder structure) as well as file permissions, etc.